# is there a way to shorten this if statement condition? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am just making this short but if there are lots of conditions in this if statement, is there a way to shorten it?

```
if(($post->id <= 37) || ($post->id == 42) || ($post->id == 44) || ($post->id == 45) || ($post->id == 46))){
    //code here
}
```

it'll all be id but the number would be different and there's no ranging or old / even numbers just randoms

Is there a way to make it shorter?

Comment: if `id > 18` then `id` is always greater than 4 and 12?

Comment: If the `id` is greater than 18 you don't need to check if it is greater than 4 and 12.. maybe you can provide a functional example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @samrap sorry was just making it random earlier I edited the codes but this would be more and more because sometimes the id would not be in sequal

Comment: If you have multiple `==` conditionals you could shorten them using `in_array()` -> `if($post->id <= 37 || in_array($post->id, array(42,44,45,46)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($post->id <= 37 || in_array( $post->id, array( 42,44,45,46)))
```